# Library built for multiple .Net Framework platform

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-framework-version

I have built a C# class library on the .Net framework 4.5.1. I am using the Json.Net library. However I would to have the same class library be compiled for at least .Net 2.0, 3.5 and 4 and packaged as nuget package. The reason why I am saying that is the only thing that change is the Json.Net because it is built to run on different .Net platform. I have read many suggestions online. However I would like to have a step by step guidance to put this up and running.

So far what I have done is to create various projects and change the target framework and build them to get the dll. Now I would like to have it in one if it is possible.

Comment: You can't target multiple framework versions in a single project. You will have to make them individual projects, although you could use the "linking" feature to link to all the same source code in each project.

Comment: +1 for separate projects, each targeting different version of .NET and appropriate JsonNet.dll